# How to skip LoggingApplicationLIstener.initialize on /refresh

Tags: spring-cloud-config

we are creating loggers through xml config then customizing the loggers through code. The problem is when we call /refresh the loggers get reloaded from xml but the custom code is not run again.

Is there anyway to skip the re-initialization of the LoggingApplicationLIstener on a refresh call?

I could reload the custom log configuration in a @RefreshScope bean but there is no guarantee it would get called after the loggers are re-initialized.